# Why my bar chart has weird fills and incorrect order? (R)

Tags: r

Could someone please point out what is the reason my bar chart has these weird looking lines/fills inside it and when I reorder category by views, it doesn't work?

My data is below. I was to have a bar chart of sum of views by category (not counts) and order by descending of total views.

```
    category views
    1        100
    2        12
    1        5
    10       98
    .        .
    .        . 
    .        .
```

My code:

```
    gplot(data=data, aes(x=reorder(category, views), y=views)) +
geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity") +
coord_flip()
```

[image: My Bar chart]

Comment: The question you mentioned is different, I am looking for a sum of views for each category, not count of each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the x axis, it appears you are plotting lots observations separately. You are getting weird black banding as these are the borders of each of these separate observations. Here is a reproducible example confirming the behaviour:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(category = 1:15, views = sample(1:300), size = 3000, replace = T))

# plot the graph
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=reorder(category, views), y=views)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

You have two ways to fix this:

- **Change the aes argument from `colour` to `fill`**: this will make the bar black
- **Group the data before plotting**: if you are actually trying to colour the outlines of the bars, then aggregating the data into groups before you plot it works best

Here is the second approach:

```
# aggregate before plotting
data_sum <- aggregate(views ~ category, data = data, FUN = sum)

ggplot(data=data_sum, aes(x=reorder(category, views), y=views)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I am failing to replicate your issue of orders with the dataset provided. But aggregating the data should resolve this I believe.

Comment: Thank you! This explains well why graph has the borders.